# GridViewDataBinaryImageColumn Can Not show image

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

I want to create grid view with binary image column. The source is image path from database.
But the image doesn't appear.

```
<dx:GridViewDataBinaryImageColumn Caption="Image" FieldName="Image_Path"
                    VisibleIndex="7" Width="20%">
                    <PropertiesBinaryImage ImageHeight="150" ImageWidth="225" EnableServerResize="True" ImageUrlFormatString="Image_Path">
                    <EditingSettings Enabled="true" UploadSettings-UploadValidationSettings-MaxFileSize="4194304"/>
                    </PropertiesBinaryImage>
                    <SettingsHeaderFilter>
                        <DateRangePickerSettings EditFormatString="" />
                    </SettingsHeaderFilter>
                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <CellStyle HorizontalAlign="Center">
                    </CellStyle>
                </dx:GridViewDataBinaryImageColumn>
```

Is there any mistake with my asp code? Thanks

Comment: Can you show complete `GridView` markup (and possible page code-behind)? I think this problem may caused from automatically generated columns.

Answer (score 1):

[`GridViewDataBinaryImageColumn` documentation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/AspNet/DevExpress.Web.GridViewDataBinaryImageColumn.class) remarks section said this:

> The **ASPxGridView doesn't automatically generate binary image columns
>   (provided that the ASPxGridView.AutoGenerateColumns option is
>   enabled)**. You should manually create the binary image column and bind
>   it to a data field that contains images in the binary format.

You can create `GridViewDataBinaryImageColumn` manually by setting `AutoGeneratedColumns="False"` in `GridView` markup:

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGeneratedColumns="False" ...>
    <%-- other settings --%>

    <Columns>
        <%-- other column settings --%>

        <dx:GridViewDataBinaryImageColumn Caption="Image" FieldName="Image_Path"
                VisibleIndex="7" Width="20%">

            <%-- binary image column settings --%>

        </dx:GridViewDataBinaryImageColumn>
        <%-- other column settings --%>

    </Columns>

    <%-- other settings --%>
</dx:ASPxGridView>
```

Or creating it manually by code behind `DataBound` event if you want to retain `AutoGeneratedColumns` set as true:

```
protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    ASPxGridView grid = sender as ASPxGridView;

    // check if row "Image_Path" exists
    if (grid.Columns.IndexOf(grid.Columns["Image_Path"]) != -1)
        return;

    var column = new GridViewDataBinaryImageColumn();
    column.FieldName = "Image_Path";
    column.Caption = "Image";

    // other binary image column settings

    grid.Columns.Add(column);
}
```

Related issues:

[How to display a binary image when columns are created automatically](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T454110/aspxgridview-how-to-display-a-binary-image-when-columns-are-created-automatically)

[Binary Image not displaying in ASPXGridView](http://Binary%20Image%20not%20displaying%20in%20ASPXGridView)

[How to add a column if the AutoGenerateColumns property is set to true](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E3587/aspxgridview-how-to-add-a-column-if-the-autogeneratecolumns-property-is-set-to-true)